# Silverlight custom control's content in scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I have a Silverlight control derived from ContentControl.
I use it in following way

```
<local:CustomControl>
 <local:AnotherControl>
</local:CustomControl>
```

I want to have the content (i.e. AnotherControl) in a ScrollViewer.
Without changing the above XAML usage, how can I have the content in scrollviewer? What modification do I need to make in CustomControl's template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this
I defined control template as following

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
        <ScrollViewer>
          <Canvas>
           <ContentPresenter/>
          </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Its working for me. Is it the proper way?